# How to properly sandbox AWS lambda invocations

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, sandbox

I need to run two processes in sandboxed environments:

1. support a REST call with functionality that accesses internal
       data but runs untrusted code.
2. support asynchronous event calls
       that also access internal data but runs untrusted code.

I was expecting that the lambda functions would be more or less identical for these, by providing the same library access. I was not planning to restrict access to the operating system within the lambda function because the lambda function is anyway sandboxed. However, in the interim, I've discovered that while a lambda function is kept warm, it keeps the container instance alive, so any files written by an execution may be accessible in the next execution. This is bad if the data in the file contains information confidential to the account that was being processed in the previous run.

So, how can I set this up so that any files created in one execution are inaccessible in another execution or automatically removed once the lambda exits?

Note that I'm only thinking about files, but I guess it's possible for other nasty things to happen like one process could set up a daemon process that stays alive after the lambda has exited.

If I'm wrong about this and the information I've gleaned on the internet is wrong, please feel free to shoot it down.

Comment: How about keeping your files on S3 and not having to worry about this?

Comment: I can't prevent the use of the local filesystem because the untrusted code being run is allowed to process files, e.g. processing uploaded zip packages or creating PDFs.